# How do you change the default environment value in ASP.NET 5 that is available via IHostingEnvironment?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am accessing the environment name using IHostingEnvironment in ASP.NET 5 and it is Development by default.

How do I change it to something else? I tried creating environment variable ASPNET_ENV in my Windows 7 system but that doesn't change anything.

> Update: The problem was resolved when I removed the ASPNET_ENV variable from the visual studio project properties.

Comment: How do you create the environment variable? Is it actually available to the process starting your website?

Comment: @VictorHurdugaci I am setting environment variable ASPNET_ENV using Advanced System Settings and it is created at system level so it should be available to the process I guess.

Comment: If you do it that way then you have to restart any running process that needs that variable. Processes only pick environment variables from their parent when they start.

Comment: I did try restarting visual studio (I am debugging app through VS2015) but it doesn't work either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should pick it up. 99.9% of me believes that you need to make sure your refresh the environment variables cache (e.g. VS needs restart if you changed the environment variable after you started the VS).

Comment: Tried restarting visual studio but no luck

Comment: @Mani can you open up a new cmd window and run `echo %ASPNET_ENV%` and see if you really have it there?

Comment: I did that and it prints the value I set in using Advanced Settings

Comment: It works after deleting the environment variable in Project properties in Visual Studio.